# IPasswordHasher.HashPassword is creating a hash which causes an invalid length exception with IPasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword

Tags: c#, asp.net, hash, asp.net-identity, identity

I couldn't seem to find an answer for this error I am coming across.

I am using `IPasswordHasher.HashPassword` to create the hashed version of a user's security question answer.

```
public string HashAnswer(string answer)
{
    return _passwordHasher.HashPassword(answer.ToLower().CalculateMd5Hash());
}
```

The `CalculateMd5Hash` function is the same as whats provided via google:

```
public static string CalculateMd5Hash(this string input)
    {
        var md5 = MD5.Create();
        var inputBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
        var hash = md5.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (var i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
        {
            sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Im finding very very rarely, there will be a user who gets an Invalid base-64 length exception from the `hashedAnswer` (which is generated by the `HashAnswer` function) being passed into the `IPasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword` function:

```
public PasswordVerificationResult VerifyHashedAnswer(string hashedAnswer, string providedAnswer)
    {
        return _passwordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(hashedAnswer, providedAnswer.ToLower().CalculateMd5Hash());
    }
```

> Exception: System.FormatException
> Message: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.
> Source: mscorlib
> at System.Convert.FromBase64_Decode(Char* startInputPtr, Int32 inputLength, Byte* startDestPtr, Int32 destLength)
> at System.Convert.FromBase64CharPtr(Char* inputPtr, Int32 inputLength)
> at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)
> at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(String hashedPassword, String password)
> at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.PasswordHasher.VerifyHashedPassword(String hashedPassword, String providedPassword)

`Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword` passes the `hashedPassword` to `Convert.FromBase64String()` which is causing the exception.

I am unable to replicate this exception no matter what string I am putting into the `HashAnswer` function.

Comment: Why are you hashing the password with MD5 before passing it to the hash function?

Comment: what value you have in `hashedAnswer` ?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar - its existing code built however many years ago, probably was an additional level of security when it was implemented.

Comment: I see. I'd suggest adding logging to at least determine the length of the hashed password. The base64 that C# uses expects that it should be a multiple of 4 characters.

Comment: @Chetan unfortunately I cant get what the value was which was passed into hashedAnswer at the time this exception happened as its a customer's security answer which for obvious reasons we are not allowed to know, but for example when I test this myself it's 'AKM3uHwjo/vAURck6VSWyjlRD1VQ7Y3GdS6Q+WESTNI9y+GsWGkmqjTnnTjS48NtKg==' which is a valid base 64 string

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar hmm yes thats definitely a good option, unfortunately the question remains why an invalid length base 64 string would be generated from the Microsoft HashPassword function as the Md5 value will always be a 32 character hexadecimal string

Comment: @Adam Perhaps someone with more access to the database could scan the hashed password field to make sure that all entries are valid base64 (a multiple of 4 characters long, composed of + / = and alphanumeric characters). It might be possible that an earlier bug in your code introduced the problem.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar even better idea! Thanks for that mate